# Mutliple plots not showing when using DatetimeIndex

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I want to create a figure with one line plot and a bar plot together. This code doesnt show the 2 plots I am creating (only one of them is displayed):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'abnormal' : [90,40,30,30,30,25,25,20,15,10],
 'fix' : [60,70,65,70,70,60,50,45,45,45],
 'normal' : [140,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240],
 'bad_rate' : [210,100,100,70,70,75,70,60,65,60]})
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=10, freq='Y')), inplace=True)

df['abnormal'].plot(kind='bar')
df['bad_rate'].plot(secondary_y=True)

plt.show()
```

However, if not using the DatetimeIndex, it shows correctly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'abnormal' : [90,40,30,30,30,25,25,20,15,10],
 'fix' : [60,70,65,70,70,60,50,45,45,45],
 'normal' : [140,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240],
 'bad_rate' : [210,100,100,70,70,75,70,60,65,60]})
#df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=10, freq='Y')), inplace=True)

df['abnormal'].plot(kind='bar')
df['bad_rate'].plot(secondary_y=True)

plt.show()
```

I can't see what is wrong here.

Comment: still, just showing the line plot

Comment: it shows both but the barplot is wrongly placed on the timeline!

Comment: It is showing the bar plot as if it started in 1970 instead of what is in its index (2010-01-01). I dont understand why and how to fix it.

Comment: But then why if I comment out the line plot (df['bad_rate'].plot(secondary_y=True)) it does start at 2010-01-01, correctly?

Comment: Sorry I may be missing some knowledge here. I cant find a way to fix this!

Comment: Should I subtract with a timedelta from the index of the line plot? Or is there a hidden parameter to the .plot method that allows for defining an offset for the bar plot?

Comment: I tried this with no luck: ax = df['abnormal'].plot(x=df['abnormal'].index.year.tolist(), kind='bar')

Comment: ax = df['abnormal'].plot(x=df['abnormal'].index.year.tolist(), kind='bar') .... then ....
df['bad_rate'].plot(x=df['abnormal'].index.year.tolist(), secondary_y=True, ax=ax) .... wont do it.

Comment: Tried this:
years = df['abnormal'].index.year.tolist(); df.index = years; ax = df['abnormal'].plot(kind='bar'); df['bad_rate'].plot(secondary_y=True)
still no luck

Comment: It only displays the barplot from 2010 to 2019. No lineplot when index is a list of integers!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the year as the x-values and plot directly from matplotlib:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df.index.year, df['abnormal'], color='b')
sec_ax = ax.twinx()
sec_ax.plot(df.index.year, df['bad_rate'])
```

Output:

[image]